# Change title - moderncv - error stack size

Tags: errors, moderncv

I'm using moderncv and when I write this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\firstname{\textcolor{darkgray}{zzzzzzzzzzz}}
\familyname{\textcolor{darkgray}{zzzzzzzzzzz}}
\title{\textcolor{darkgray}{zzzzzzzzzzz}}       
\address{\textcolor{darkgray}{zzzzzzzzzzz}\textcolor{darkgray}{zzzzzzzzzzz}}    
\mobile{\textcolor{darkgray}{zzzzzzzzzzz}}                   
\email{\textcolor{darkgray}{zzzzzzzzzzz}}                      

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{\medbreak}
\section{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{\bigbreak}{\medbreak}
\cventry{pppppp}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{}{}{\smallbreak}
\cventry{ffff}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{}{}{\bigbreak}{\medbreak}
\section{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{\bigbreak}{\medbreak}
\subsection{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{\medbreak}{\smallbreak}
\cventry{kkkk}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{}
{zzzzzzzzzzz}
\cventry{kkkkkk}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{\bigbreak}
\subsection{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{\medbreak}{\smallbreak}
\cventry{2013}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{Java}{}{}{}{\smallbreak}
\cventry{}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{VB.Net}{}{}{}{\smallbreak}
\cventry{}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{}{}{}{\smallbreak}
\cventry{2012}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{C++}{}{}{}{\smallbreak}
\cventry{}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{C}{}{}{\medbreak}
\section{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{\bigbreak}{\medbreak}
\subsection{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{\medbreak}
\cvcomputer{yyyy}{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{\smallbreak}
\cvcomputer{yyyy}{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz} zzzzzzzzzzz}{}{}{\bigbreak}{\medbreak}
\subsection{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{\medbreak}
\cvlanguage{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{}{\smallbreak}
\cvlanguage{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{}{\bigbreak}{\medbreak}
\section{\textbf{zzzzzzzzzzz}}{\bigbreak}{\medbreak}
\cventry{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{}{}{}{}{\smallbreak}
\cventry{zzzzzzzzzzz}{zzzzzzzzzzz}{}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

I have this error :

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].

So how can I fixe it ?

Thanks you very much ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email link in [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) is formatted via the `\emaillink` macro:

```
% makes an email hyperlink
% usage: \emaillink[optional text]{link}
\newcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}
```

These elements cannot be combined explicitly with colour the way you do it. You would have to update `\emaillink` to format the text colour (in your preamble):

```
% makes an email hyperlink
% usage: \emaillink[optional text]{link}
\renewcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\textcolor{darkgray}{\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}}%
    {\textcolor{darkgray}{\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}}
```

and then use

```
%...
\email{zzzzzzzzzzz}
```

[image]

Perhaps a better approach would be to allow the user to specify

```
% \email[<optional email formatting/display>]{<email>}
\email[\textcolor{darkgray}{zzzzzzzzzzz}]{zzzzzzzzzzz}
```

but this would require some inner workings of the class.